# Does making an SSL POST request to LinkedIn require that my server is listening to port 443?

Tags: ssl, linkedin-api

When making an SSL POST request to LinkedIn does my own server need to have SSL enabled or be listening on port 443 in order to receive the response?

I'm sending a request like this (I've modified the actual code, api keys, etc.)

```
POST /uas/oauth2/accessToken HTTP/1.1
Host: www.linkedin.com
Referer: http://www.myserver.com/LinkedProfile
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 265

grant_type=authorization_code&code=AQREV6hhRbPCiWbbQSjTFNGELYeaGmwf65mzn6GHRN7273ma6JEq1gjCvMU0dI0Ury4smE6LkJdI_w-VSPiCA1j58&redirect_uri=http://www.myserver.com/LinkedProfile&client_id=75jv8rkdp&client_secret=dccBktuhC
```

Before people jump all over me and downgrade my question, there is no other place to ask, since StackOverflow is the support site for LinkedIn and my question is related to a programming call - my code is making an SSL POST to LinkedIn but can't negotiate and I'm trying to figure out why.

So please take some pity on me and somebody just answer the question instead of ganging up on me and clicking the down arrow.

Much thanks,

doug

Comment: Are you getting a response when posting?

Comment: Hi Mez. Naturally some troll has come by and marked my question down immediately again. Anyway, thanks for your comment. I'm getting a negotiation failure that it can't handshake with SSL3. My server uses TLS 1, yet also has SSL3 enabled. So I was wondering what a connecting server needs to have on in order to connect correctly. For example, does port 443 have to be open to listening in order to receive a reply? (By the time all the people who don't want to help knock down my question overnight I'll probably end up deleting it, but in the meanwhile, if anybody knows...) Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you go through this link which elaborates what is required to connect via SSL http://robertheaton.com/2014/03/27/how-does-https-actually-work/.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to answer my own question after doing some more tests with a different server and successfully receiving responses from the LinkedIn People API. SSL on my web server itself does not need to be enabled. I'm assuming that PHP itself is making a proper TLS call to the LinkedIn server and getting the response, and that is separate from the Apache server's SSL settings (which I have disabled). Thanks for responses everybody.

Answer (score 1):

The SSL heartbleed vulnerability that was surfaced a while ago caused many service providers to stop support for SSL3.  LinkedIn, Facebook, and many other services stopped supporting SSL3 as a result.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Right. I realize now that the outbound request must be made with a client (e.g. PHP) which can make an TLS1.0+ connection with the LinkedIn server. What I was trying to figure out was if my outbound requests have to be from a server that is also capable of receiving TLS. In other words, must it have a signed certificate itself for listening?